# Creating and updating entities with a many to many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In an ASP.NET core (dotnet 6) web application, we have a small user management functionality in which a user can be assigned to a specific site (physical location) with certain rights. A user can be assigned to one or more sites and a site can also be assigned to one or more users, thus the many to many relationship. We have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserSite> UserSites { get; set; }
}

public class Site
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public ICollection<UserSite> UserSites { get; set; }
}
```

The many to many relationship is described in a join table with fluent API:

```
public class UserSite
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
    public Site Site { get; set; }
}

// Fluent API for UserSite table
builder.HasKey(us => new { us.UserID, us.SiteID });

builder.HasOne(us => us.User)
       .WithMany(us => us.UserSites)
       .HasForeignKey(us => us.UserID)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

builder.HasOne(us => us.Site)
       .WithMany(us => us.UserSites)
       .HasForeignKey(us => us.SiteID)
       .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

These classes result in the following DTO's:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SamAccountName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int GroupID { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    public IList<SiteDTO> Sites { get; set; }
}

public class SiteDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

What we want to know is, what is the best way to create a new user or update an existing user? Just to clarify, the data in the Sites table exists already and is static. What I mean by that is that when creating a new user or updating an existing one, a user can be assigned to one or more existing sites, but no new site is created in the process.

We already tried some things that did work but we are not sure if this is really the best way to this or if there is a far better way to do it. Here is what we tried:

The create method

```
// Create method
public IActionResult CreateUser(UserDTO userDTO)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = _mapper.Map<User>(userDTO);
        user.IsEnabled = true;
        AttachSitesToUser(user.ID, user.UserSites);
        _context.Users.Add(user);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        userViewModel = _mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(user);
    }
    return new JsonResult(new[] { userDTO });
}
```

The update method:

```
// Update method
public IActionResult UpdateUser(UserDTO userDTO)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User user = _context.Users
                            .Include(u => u.Sites)
                            .ThenInclude(s => s.Site)
                            .Single(u => u.ID == userDTO.ID);
        _mapper.Map(userViewModel, user);
        AttachSitesToUser(user.ID, user.UserSites);
        _context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    return new JsonResult(new[] { userDTO });
}
```

The helper method AttachSitesToUser:

```
// Helper method that adds the user ID and attaches the site(s) to the context
private void AttachSitesToUser(int userID, IEnumerable<UserSite> userSites)
{
    foreach (UserSite userSite in userSites)
    {
        userSite.UserID = userID;

        if (Context.Entry<Site>(userSite.Site).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Context.Sites.Attach(userSite.Site);
            Context.Entry<Site>(userSite.Site).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, for the moment we have to loop through the UserSites list in the User entity and attach the sites the user was assigned to manually to the context. Is there no better way to do this or is this the official best practice?

Comment: It looks like you are following the way in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/update-related-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0), there is no problem. We recommend that you use the way of official document to operate.

Comment: @Chen This is the example we were looking for. This helps us a lot already. Thank you very much